# Import only one profile of library built with maven

Tags: java, maven, build

I have two profiles in my pom.xml. A default and another is used to build swagger client library. I import this library in my another maven project. The problem is that it uses all the dependencies from the first project, even those that are mentioned in default profile. What is the best way to solve the problem? Is it possible to put only one profile in pom file when generating jar? Or is it possible to choose a profile when importing a dependency?

Comment: split it into a multi module project with 2 children, one for each jar.

Comment: We once constructed a structure where one project deploys two different poms generated from profiles. It was necessary for some legacy compatibility issue, but it was a nightmare.

Comment: @EssexBoy thank you! I've created a parent pom and two pom files for each profile. It works great, but now I have another problem - when I try to use client lib as a dependency it requires an artifact for a parent pom.I don't want to flood our repository with useless artifacts, so, is there a workaround for this problem?

Comment: @НикитаМихайлов see answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need something like this

1) a parent that holds it all together

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
  <artifactId>hm-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <name>hm-parent</name>

  <modules>
    <module>hm-client</module>
    <module>hm-default</module>
  </modules>

</project>
```

2) A client module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>hm-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>hm-client</artifactId>
  <name>hm-client</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

3) A default module that pulls the client in from the same project under the same parent

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <parent>
    <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
    <artifactId>hm-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </parent>

  <artifactId>hm-default</artifactId>
  <name>hm-default</name>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.greg</groupId>
      <artifactId>hm-client</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: This is the best solution, but if someone wants to avoid importing parent pom you can use maven's flatten plugin. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51467023/maven-self-contained-child-artifact