# Maven self-contained child artifact

Tags: java, maven, nexus

I have a project which has 3 pom files: parent file (very basic one, just declares its children), main pom for building project itself and a pom file for generating swagger client library. The client artifact is getting downloaded into our Nexus.

The problem is that when I want to use a client library in another project as a dependency it also requires a parent artifact. I don't want to download it into Nexus since it's so basic and will only flood the repository. I've tried packing some kind of an uber-jar, but it doesn't work for me - jar is huge and contains all dependencies, yet it still needs parent artifact. Are there any workarounds?

Comment: I would really ask you what is the real problem having a number of parent poms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I generally would not care about having an additional Parent POM in the repository (our repository contains 2000 different self-created artifacts in various versions, it is not "flooded"), you can have a look at the

https://www.mojohaus.org/flatten-maven-plugin/

which allows you to make your pom smaller, and includes the possibility to get away without a Parent POM.

Comment: @khmarbaise You may be right, I haven't tried it and might have misunderstood the description.

Comment: Looks like it works just fine. I had to wipe out my local repository for some reason, cause it kept asking for a parent pom, but after all it worked. Might need some testing, but so far so good. Thank you, @JFMeier !